# who wins with three pairs if both players have the same three pairs?

Tags: texas-hold-em

this is a kicker question on 3 pairs. the board is QQ885. I have 5-4 and my oponent has 5-2. Are the 5s dead and I would win with the 4 kicker?

Comment: simply put the player with the best two pair or the best kicker

Comment: I am closing this because it is a duplicate, simply put 3 pair is a six card hand, only the best five cards play. read more in the link to the post on how to determine the winning hand

Answer (score 0):

The best hands you can form with either QQ88554 and QQ88552 are both QQ885, so you split. Cards not in the hand aren't in the hand so don't affect the ranking; you don't have 3 pairs but 2 pair with 5 kicker, otherwise you would allow 6 card hands.